# Как лучше написать SELECT для переводов товара?

Tags: postgresql, select, перевод

есть таблица `product` и `product_translate`

для одного товара есть переводы на нескольких языках

нам нужно выбрать язык который лучше понимает пользователь (имееться его id) если такого перевода нет, то выбираем любой другой

это всё в одном запросе

как лучше написать?

`product_translate`:

[image]

можно подзапросы использовать, но придёться 2 подзапроса написать, 1 для `title`, 2 для `description`

и ещё не понятно как написать `ORDER BY` в подзапросах

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id 
                                ORDER BY (language_id = @id) DESC) rn
             FROM product_translate)
SELECT *
FROM product
LEFT JOIN cte ON product.product_id = cte.product_id 
             AND cte.rn = 1
-- WHERE product.product_id IN (product IDs list)
```

Comment: а можете как-то комментировать `WITH`?

Comment: @ValeriuVodnicear Пардон, а что именно тут комментировать? Что именно неясно? Вы бы выразились поконкретнее... конечно, прочитав предварительно, что такое CTE и что это за функция там использована.

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто:

Соедините таблицы `product` и `product_translate` через `left join` и используйте `coalesce`:

```sql
select
    coalesce(pt.title, p.title) as title,
    coalesce(pt.description, p.description) as description
from product p
left join product_translate t on
    t.product_id = p.id and
    t.language_id = 1 -- для языка с id = 1
where p.id = 2 -- для товара с id = 2
```